# PCI Card Number Definition

Tags: pci-dss

We are using a truncation strategy to eliminate card numbers.   In order to develop, I need the original pre-truncated data files.    The test environment is not allowed to have live card numbers.    I wrote a program that basically obfuscates the card numbers.   The deal is that occasionally numbers are going to validate as card numbers.   I’m dealing with thousands of files and millions of card numbers.

For example:

Card Number
37111234569999

Obfuscated to:
37110000009999

So we know that 37111234569999 is an active, currently used card number in our system.  37110000009999 would not be an active, currently used card number but it could validate as one.

My question is would 37110000009999 be considered card data or not?   If it would be considered card data, then how are we supposed to test systems with lots of data?

I have looked on the pci website and cannot find a specific enough definition.

Comment: This is probably best answered by your company's legal team. I wouldn't suggest migrating to the legal stack exchange site, since the answer depends on the company's specific risk averseness.  (PCI-DSS is something I consider more of a "Please don't sue me" standard rather than a "We want to be secure" standard.)

Comment: "In order to develop, I need the original pre-truncated data files." -- no, you ***really*** don't. Don't try to perform "test-driven development" where you test successful tests against prod. That's a$$ backwards. You need a radically different approach.

Comment: Is your question actually ["where do I get test card numbers for development?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+do+I+get+test+credit+card+numbers+for+development) That's a simple question with many available answers.

Comment: @schroeder  I am dealing with millions of card numbers, thousands of files and an open number of file formats.   I need be as close to the raw file format as possible.   Sadly I can’t  design tests without reports.   I recognize that may be hard to understand but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3):

*(answer substantially edited. Original in Edit History)*

PCI-DSS gives this guidance on truncation of PANs:

> The intent of truncation is to permanently remove a segment of PAN data so that only a portion (generally not to exceed the first six and last four digits) of the PAN is stored.

So your example of

```
Card Number 37111234569999
Obfuscated to: 37110000009999
```

May actually fit. However, you'll also need to be careful about this note and make sure you can demonstrate that to an auditor's satisfaction:

> *Note: It is a relatively trivial effort for a malicious individual to reconstruct original PAN data if they have access to both the truncated and hashed version of a PAN. Where hashed and truncated versions of the same PAN are present in an entity’s environment, additional controls must be in place to ensure that the hashed and truncated versions cannot be correlated to reconstruct the original PAN.*

---

I am not a PCI auditor. You say that you have millions of entries of live card data flowing into your test environment and you're trying to sanitize them on the way by. That's *really close* to **wrong** and only one code bug or missed edge-case away from having live data in your test environment.

As @Ghedipunk said in comments, if I was your Legal & Compliance team, I would not accept some random opinion from some random website as authoritative here; you should really hire a certified PCI auditor to get an official ruling on this.

Comment: I am dealing with millions of card numbers so I’m hoping for a mix of similar looking data and not the several dozen published by PayPal or other vendors.   For PCI, do you think it would be sufficient to restate what the program does by saying the program truncates PANs by replacing the middle six with zeros.   Consequent to that, there will occasionally be numbers that validate as card numbers but those are not known to me or our systems to be card numbers therefore are not considered PAN.

Comment: @Missy I re-vamped my answer. This really feels like you've got a fundamental architecture problem that your prod and test environments are not isolated, and you're trying to trying to find a cheap&dirty bandaid fix. The right answer is to not have live data flowing into TEST at all. If you're trying to get a hack past an auditor, I think you've really got to ask an auditor.

Comment: Thanks for your revised answer.   The card data is actually flowing into it’s own environment and it is completely isolated.   The substitution happens in the card data environment before the files are passed to me in development.   Live card data is not going into development.   I very much appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need a file from production in order to do your development - you should be able to mock one up from the specification you're working from, or ask the company sending it to you whether they have a test environment that generates fake files.

That said, depending on how closely your data needs to mimic production, there's two options that don't involve bringing anything back from production (with all the compliance issues that causes).

#### Test cards

There's a number of standard test card numbers that the card brands have indicated will never be issued - [this link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm) has a list of some of them, but there are others.  Assuming duplicate values don't cause issues with your file, just generate it with randomly chosen test cards.  They may *look* like PCI data, but they're safe.

#### Randomly generated PANs

If you really need uniqueness, your next best option is to just randomly generate PANs.  Odds are fairly decent that the numbers you come up with are actually a real card number, just because any sixteen digit number with the right prefix could be, but since it's not actually based on real cards you shouldn't have too much trouble from an auditor.  Just be prepared to show the process you used to generate them.  Even better if you put in a block of 0's somewhere (digits 2-6?) just to make it clear it's not valid.

Superficially, this would look the same as the method you were suggesting.  But because the numbers are being pulled out of a hat rather than scrubbed from production, 1) you won't know whether or not any given card is actually valid and 2) even if it happens to be, you won't have the expiration date associated with that card.

#### If all else fails...

If for some reason neither of these is workable options, and you absolutely *must* have scrubbed production data, then you're going to need to sit down with your legal department and your auditor, explain the situation, and see what will be acceptable to them.  Your method *could* be good enough for them, but as the other answer says, it's very easy to miss a line of code and fail to mask correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   I do need scrubbed production data - and the scrubbing is happening in the CDE - but I do understand your concerns.   You zeroed in on it because I really won’t know if any card numbers are valid and we don’t store exp dates or any other card specific data anywhere.     That is what I need to communicate to the auditor.

Answer (score 1):

I think PCI SSC FAQ 1091 is your friend.

https://pcissc.secure.force.com/faq/articles/Frequently_Asked_Question/What-are-acceptable-formats-for-truncation-of-primary-account-numbers

You need to be able to show an assessor that '0' is your truncation character (rather than *), and yes, you may randomly have a truncated PAN that passes a luhn check, but it is not an actual card that you have received in a transaction. But you should be fine exporting truncated data from the CDE to the test environment based on an acceptable truncation format based on this FAQ. You will need to prove isolation between the CDE (where the truncation happens) and the test environment.